# Third Mandelbrot's The Charm

Tags: c#, fractals, mandelbrot

for the third time, my project has been malfunctioning. Not malfunctioning per se, but it is absolutely not doing what I need it to do. So, basically, I need to draw a mandelbrot fractal. It needs to accept data from the user like maximum iterations, color, scale, middle x, and middle y. These middle coordinates are what's giving me problems. I have no idea how to make it so the mandelbrot fractal has the middle x and middle y as its midpoint in the image. Could you guys help me out please?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace practicum_2_poging_2_officieel
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int hoogte = 400, breedte = 400;
    double xInput, yInput, scaleNum;

    TextBox xInputBox;
    TextBox yInputBox;
    TextBox scaleInputBox;
    TextBox maxInputBox;
    Button okButton;
    PictureBox pictureBox;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ComboBox comboBox;
    Label middleX;
    Label middleY;
    Label schaal;
    Label max;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //form aanpassen mooie kleurtjes en naam.
        this.Text = "Mandelbrot Bjorn Jonathan:";
        this.ClientSize = new Size(500, 600);
        this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;


        //Labels plaats + sizes e.d.
        middleX = new Label();
        middleX.Location = new Point(20, 10);
        middleX.Size = new Size(55, 20);
        middleX.Text = "Midden X:";

        middleY = new Label();
        middleY.Location = new Point(20, 40);
        middleY.Size = new Size(55, 20);
        middleY.Text = "Midden Y:";

        schaal = new Label();
        schaal.Location = new Point(180, 10);
        schaal.Size = new Size(55, 20);
        schaal.Text = "Schaal:";

        max = new Label();
        max.Location = new Point(180, 40);
        max.Size = new Size(90, 20);
        max.Text = "Max herhalingen:";

        //Textbox
        this.xInputBox = new TextBox();
        this.xInputBox.Location = new Point(80, 10);
        this.xInputBox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
        xInputBox.Text = "-2";

        this.yInputBox = new TextBox();
        this.yInputBox.Location = new Point(80, 40);
        this.yInputBox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
        yInputBox.Text = "2";

        this.scaleInputBox = new TextBox();
        this.scaleInputBox.Location = new Point(270, 10);
        this.scaleInputBox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
        scaleInputBox.Text = "0.01";

        this.maxInputBox = new TextBox();
        this.maxInputBox.Location = new Point(270, 40);
        this.maxInputBox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
        maxInputBox.Text = "100";

        //OK okButton
        okButton = new Button();
        okButton.Location = new Point(390, 10);
        okButton.Size = new Size(80, 30);
        okButton.Text = "OK";

        //Box
        pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Location = new Point(20, 75);
        pictureBox.Size = new Size(400, 400);

        //bitmap
        //Midden bitmap = (252 + 20, 280 +75) = (272, 355)
        bitmap = new Bitmap(breedte, hoogte);

        //Combobox
        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.Location = new Point(390, 40);
        comboBox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
        comboBox.Text = "W";
        comboBox.Items.Add("W");
        comboBox.Items.Add("R");
        comboBox.Items.Add("G");
        comboBox.Items.Add("B");


        //Alle Controls.Add
        //Controls voor labels
        this.Controls.Add(middleX);
        this.Controls.Add(middleY);
        this.Controls.Add(max);
        this.Controls.Add(schaal);

        //Controls.Add voor textboxen
        this.Controls.Add(this.xInputBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.yInputBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.scaleInputBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.maxInputBox);

        //Controls voor Box
        this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

        //okButton
        this.Controls.Add(okButton);

        //Ok en Enter zorgt voor startbereken
        okButton.Click += Invoer;
        okButton.Click += StartBerekening;

        //okButton.Click += Kleuren;
        this.AcceptButton = okButton; //voor enterokButton

        //Controls voor combobox
        this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        //this.Paint += StartBerekening;
    }

    private void Invoer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scaleNum = Convert.ToDouble(scaleInputBox.Text);
    }

    //private void StartBerekening(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    private void StartBerekening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double yInput = Convert.ToDouble(yInputBox.Text);
        double xInput = Convert.ToDouble(xInputBox.Text);
        //ComboBox doubleRead = (ComboBox)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        string combVal = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        char combChar = combVal[0];
        for (double x = 0; x < breedte; x++)
        {
            for (double y = 0; y < hoogte; y++)
            {
                int MandelGetal;
                double a, b, Distance, a2;
                xInput = (x - 200) * scaleNum;
                yInput = (y - 200) * scaleNum;
                MandelGetal = 0;

                // a en b op 0
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                a2 = a;

                //Afstand berekenen tussen O(0,0) en punt P(x,y) mbv Pythagoras
                //Begin distance
                Distance = Math.Pow((Math.Pow(xInput, 2) + Math.Pow(yInput, 2)), 0.5);

                while (Distance < 2 && MandelGetal < Convert.ToInt32(maxInputBox.Text))
                {
                    //verandering van a en b door f(a,b) = (a*a-b*b+x, 2*a*b+y)
                    //a = gebruikt voorgaande a en b
                    a = (a * a) - (b * b) + xInput;
                    //b = gebruikt voorgaande a en b, gebruikt nu nieuwe a
                    b = (2 * a2 * b) + yInput;

                    a2 = a;

                    Distance = Math.Pow((Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2)), 0.5);
                    MandelGetal++;
                }

                if ((MandelGetal % 2) != 0)
                {
                    switch (combChar)
                    {
                        case 'W':
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case 'R':
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), Color.Red);
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), Color.Green);
                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), Color.Blue);
                            break;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bitmap.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), Color.Black);
                }
            }
        }
        pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], there's extensive detective work going on here just to understand what all the controls are used for and so on. Remove all the controls, hard-code the input, that should cut down the amount of code drastically. For instance, right now the program crashes with a format error (since in my region, comma is used to separate decimals), and your dropdown doesn't have anything selected apparently.

Comment: You need to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Alright, I'll do both things. Thanks for the tips.